# Assign zero to float in C

Tags: floating-point, variable-assignment, zero

I've got in the habit of using float f = 0.; //with a trailing period
when assigning a zero value to a float in C.

Should I be using float f = 0.f; //with an explicit float size or just stop messing about and use float f = 0; //with no trailing anything?

Where did I pick up that habit and why?

Is any version more right or wrong than any other?

Answer (score 2):

`0.0` and `0.` are doubles, not floats. While it is legal to assign doubles to floats in C without an explicit cast, `0.0f` or `0.f` would be the correct way. `0` is an integer and thus equally wrong, but it will also 'work'.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `float f = 0;` and no trailing period.

If the trailing period and/or the trailing f or whatever makes the code easier to understand from your perspective then by all means use that. Use what works best for you and your co-workers.

Comment: It works, but on paper, it introduces an unnecessary cast. Modern compilers will probably polish it away, but technically speaking, 0.0f is the correct way.

Comment: @tdammers: Yes, I agree. Unless I hit a noticable performance issue I prefer readability over the performance benefit.

Comment: I'd consider 0.0f the most readable, but then, I'm a bit of a zealot with these details.

Answer (score 1):

trailing . or .f is just to increase readability.

`float f = 0;` is enough